# How to Add Web Part Zone in existing Page

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, page-layout, web-part-zone

[image]I have a page which has already a web part and I need to add another web part zone.

[image]

Can you please help me with this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the problem with you?

You can add another web part by clicking "Add a Web Part" button as your screenshot.

**Update**:

If your page is in Site Pages library, you can go to SharePoint Designer->Site pages in the left pane->find the page and Edit File in advanced mode.

Add insert Web Part Zone via click the botton:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I want to add another Webpart zone, not just adding another webpart.

Comment: I believe this is code is for the one I have highlighted in the screenshot.

Comment: <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main"><ZoneTemplate>
<WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{C99D07A6-B0DC-4A10-992E-E9DAB06CF56B}" >
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">

Comment: I edit the reply above, you can check it.

Comment: mine is greyed out.

Comment: refresh the page by clicking refresh button in the SharePoint Designer Quick Access Toolbar and check again.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have added the second webpart, also can I ask you how I can edit the width and height of the WebPart. ?

Comment: Check the post: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ab9a072e-8fbb-46ba-92ec-5f346057d706/how-to-make-the-web-part-and-web-part-zone-smaller?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 1):

In Order to add a new **WebPart Zone** you need to create a custom **Page Layout** and use that page layout to create your SharePoint Pages **OR** you can edit your page in SharePoint Designer and add below code snippet to it.

**Reference**: [Create a Custom Page Layout in SharePoint](http://www.sharepointsurgeon.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint/).

Then you can add below code snippet to add webpart zone to your custom page layout:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="TestZoneTitle1" ID="TestZoneID1">
    <ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

**Reference**: [Add a web part zone snippet in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-add-a-web-part-zone-snippet-in-sharepoint).

**Notes**:

1. Make sure you are putting this snippet inside `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">` block.
2. Make sure you are passing different ID to webpart zone if you are adding multiple webpart zones on your page.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, What about adding the WebPart Zone to existing page? I already have the custom page and I need to update the page with more PageLayout Zone.

Comment: Try editing this particular page in SharePoint Designer and add the code snippet given in my answer to your page....Make sure you are passing different `ID` to webpart zone if you are adding multiple webpart zones on your page. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I just updated the page in SharePoint designer and added your code under the other WebPart Zone, however when I save the it I get lots of &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp in there.

Comment: Remove the unwanted content and save it again (check-in if required). Is webpart zone added on page??

Comment: Hi, Have you figured it out? If this answer helps you please upvote ( ^ ) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).